# Change date format vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I need to change a date format to the following  format yyyyMMdd its for edi files  but the below is not working its just leaving the orderDatedb as is in same format

```
Dim orderDateDb As DateTime = orderHeaderDt.Rows(0).Item("Orderdate")
orderDateDb = Format(orderDateDb, "yyyyMMdd")
```

this is the column in db

[image]

How can i convert this to prooper format in vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the To String way...

ToString("yyyyMMdd")

You wanted a function, here it is...

```
 Public Class Form1

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Example usage...

    Dim orderDateDb As String = ConvertDateTime(orderHeaderDt.Rows(0).Item("Orderdate"))
    MessageBox.Show(orderDateDb)

 End Sub

  Public Shared Function ConvertDateTime(ByVal dtDateTime As DateTime) As String
    Return dtDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
  End Function
 End Class
```

Comment: You could even create a `Const` for the date format, say `Const EDIDATEFORMAT As String = "yyyyMMdd"` so that it can be used in more than one place and if the format needed to be changed to, say, `yyyy-MM-dd` then it could be done in just one place in the code.

Comment: Correct! @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 0):

The Way I solved this was by using this

```
   Dim orderDateDb As DateTime = orderHeaderDt.Rows(0).Item("Orderdate")
     Dim ymd As String = orderDateDb.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Using the first answer down

http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/378334-how-get-dateformat-yyyymmdd

Comment: would their be a nicer way to turn this into a resuable funciton ?

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR would their be a nicer way to turn it into resuable function without me having to do it on every field ? like that